# SURF, Built-in functions for limit Keypoints, drawmatches

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I am trying to run surf code :

I have the following questions.

1: I want to get limited keypoint (e.g.,1000) like SIFT-implementation. Is there any built-in function for that or one has to write its own function.

2: I am drawing goodmatches. It works fine but I want to draw 
**good matches with green** and **rest(matches-goodmatches) with red lines**
 on the same image ('Match_SURF.jpg').

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/line_descriptor.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d\nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    using namespace cv;
    void readme();

    /** @function main */
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {


        Mat img_object = imread("C:\\VC_examples\\IMG_0030.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat img_scene = imread("C:\\VC_examples\\IMG_0031.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
        {
            std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
        }

        //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        int minHessian = 500;
        cv::Ptr<Feature2D> detector = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(minHessian);

        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_object;
        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_scene, keypoints_scene;

        detector->detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
        detector->detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);


    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)    
    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

    detector->compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);
    detector->compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using BFMatcher :
    BFMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);        

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);
```

**Draw  "good" matches and bad matches**

```
    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
        good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
        std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);


    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);
```

**SAVE IMAGES**

```
imwrite("Match_SURF.jpg", img_matches);**

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

/** @function readme */
void readme()
{
    std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_descriptor <img1> <img2>" << std::endl;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You're missing the line: `detector->compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);`. The rest should then work almost as expected.

Comment: @miki... edited: it was missing while pasting the code.

Comment: Add C++ tag to get automatic syntax highlighting

Comment: 1) I don't know, I think you need to prune manually the keypoints 2) works for me 3) you have the two matching keypoints. Just draw a green / red line between them